# Al añadir un elemento a la tabla esta aparece vacia(Tableview)

Tags: java, javafx

Edito el post con el problema ya que tenia un fallo tonto(o eso creo) y ahora si que tengo el problema que describía pero no se como repararlo. El caso es que necesito pasar los datos que recopilo via textfields en una ventana a una tabla que tengo en otra. Para eso he creado un metodo general que abre la ventana con los textfields y dentro un botón que lleva un metodo que me añade los datos de los textfield a su correspondiente variable y luego añado el item con las variables a la lista observable.
Os dejo el codigo ya que cuando hago todo esto no me añade nada a la tabla simplemente me cierra la ventana y deja la tabla vacia sin mostrar ningún error.

Os dejo las dos clases enteras por lo que pueda pasar.
La generalController es la que contiene la tabla.
La AfegirController es la que contiene los textfields i el metodo que añade las variables i el item.
Siento las expresiones en valenciano pero al ser valencianohablante me resultaba mas facil hacerlo así. El metodo en question se encuentra en la clase AfegirController y se llama Afegir.

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controlador;
import dades.Subvencio;
import dades.SubvencioWrapper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author José Climent Penadés
 */
public class GeneralController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private MenuItem bobrir;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem bguardar;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem btancar;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem bborrar;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem bajuda;
    @FXML
    private Button bafegir;
    @FXML
    private Button bcalcular;
     @FXML
    private MenuItem beditar;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Subvencio> tabla;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Subvencio, Double> ctotal;
     @FXML
    private TableColumn<Subvencio, String> cesport;
    private static final double total = 47.000;
    ObservableList<Subvencio> subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        cesport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Subvencio, String>("Esport"));
        ctotal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Subvencio, Double>("Subvenció"));
tabla.setItems(subs);
    }


    //Mètode per carregar el filechooser per poder obrir llistats ja creats,
    @FXML
    private void obrir() throws JAXBException {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

        File subFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (subFile != null) {
            loadPresupostDataFromFile(subFile);
        }
    }

    //Metode per llegir el fitxer i carregar-lo correctament a la ferramenta.
    public void loadPresupostDataFromFile(File file) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SubvencioWrapper.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        SubvencioWrapper wrapper = (SubvencioWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);
        subs.clear();
        subs.addAll(wrapper.getSubvencions());
    }

    //Mètode per a obrir el filechooser per poder seleccionar la ruta de guardat de les subvencions.
    @FXML
    private void guardar() throws JAXBException {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        File subFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (subFile != null) {
            if (!subFile.getPath().endsWith(".xml")) {
                subFile = new File(subFile.getPath() + ".xml");
            }
            savePresupostDataToFile(subFile);
        }
    }

    //Mètode per crear un fitxer de guardat de les subvencions creades.
    public void savePresupostDataToFile(File file) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SubvencioWrapper.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        SubvencioWrapper wrapper = new SubvencioWrapper(subs);
        m.marshal(wrapper, file);
    }

    //Mètode per tancar la ferramenta, es mostrarà un misatge de confirmació avans de tancar-la.
    @FXML
    private void tancar(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
        DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
        dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
        dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
        alert.setTitle("Confirmació");
        alert.setHeaderText("Estàs a punt d'eixir de la sessió");
        alert.setContentText("Segur que vols tancar la aplicació?");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            System.out.println("Acceptar");
            Platform.exit();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cancelar");
        }
    }

    //Mètode per a esborrar un element.
    @FXML
    private void borrar(ActionEvent event) {
        int i = tabla.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (i >= 0) {
            subs.remove(i);
        }
        //En el cas de que no es seleccione un element avans de esborrar, es mostrarà un error.
        else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
            DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
            dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
            dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error al esborrar un element.");
            alert.setContentText("Deus seleccionar un element per porder utilitzar aquesta opció.");
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    //Mètode per a crear un cuadre d0informació amb les instruccions d'us de la ferramenta. 
    @FXML
    private void instruccions(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
        DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
        dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
        dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
        alert.setTitle("Intruccions");
        alert.setHeaderText("Instruccions d'us");
        alert.setContentText("Obrir: Obri un llistat de subvencions guardat previament.\n \n"
                + "Guardar: Guarda el llistat de subvencions en que se està treballant.\n \n"
                + "Tancar: Tanca la aplicació.\n \n"
                + "Editar: Edita la subvenció que esà marcada a la taula amb la informacío proporcinada.\n \n"
                + "Esborrar: Esborra la subvenció seleccionada a la taula.\n \n"
                + "Afegir: Afegix una subvencio a la llista.\n \n"
                + "Calcular: Calcula les subvencions afegides a la llista prèviament. \n \n"
                + "\n"
        );
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

        if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            System.out.println("Aceptar");
            alert.close();
        }
    }

    //Mètode per a afegir una subvenció a la llista(Mitjansant un scene diferent i un showandWait).
    @FXML
    private void afegir(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        //Carregem el controlador i inicialitzem la finestra a obrir.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/model/Afegir.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage ventana2= new Stage();
        ventana2.setMinHeight(380);
        ventana2.setMinWidth(770);
        ventana2.setTitle("Afegir dades");
        ventana2.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        ventana2.setScene(scene);
        //Fem que espere fins a ser tancada i coloquem els elements a la taula.subs = new ObservableList<Subvencio>();
        ventana2.showAndWait();
        tabla.setItems(subs);
    }

    //Mètode per al calcul de la suma dels 3 apartats.
    @FXML
    private void calcular(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++) {
            double res = calculBase(i) + calculFederada(i) + calculEvents(i);
            subs.get(i).setTotal(res);
        }
    }

    //Mètodes per al calcul de la subvenció per apartats.
    //Escola Base
    public double calculBase(int i) {
        double base = total / (45*100);
        double resEsport = 0;
        double resEquips = 0;

        resEquips = base/equipsTotals();
        resEsport = resEquips * subs.get(i).getEquips();
        return resEsport;
    }

    //Competició Federada
    public double calculFederada(int i){
    return despeses(i) + esportistes(i) + equips(i) + entrenadors(i) + socis(i);
    }

    public double despeses(int i) {
        double res = 0;
        double despE = subs.get(i).getDespeses();
        double despT = despesesTotals();

        res = (((despE*100)/despT)*4700)/100.0;
        return res;
    }
    public double esportistes(int i) {
        double res = 0;
        int espE = subs.get(i).getEsportistes();
        int espT = esportistesTotals();

        res = (((espE*100)/espT)*7050)/100.0;
        return res;
    }
    public double equips(int i) {
        double res = 0;
        int equipE = subs.get(i).getEquips();
        int equipT = equipsTotals();

        res = (((equipE*100)/equipT)*4700)/100.0;
        return res;
     }
    public double entrenadors(int i) {
        double res = 0;
        int puntE = subs.get(i).getPuntuacio();
        int puntT = puntuacioTotals();

        res = (((puntE*100)/puntT)*2350)/100.0;
        return res;
    }
    public double socis(int i) {
        double res = 0;
        int socE = subs.get(i).getSocis();
        int socT = socisTotals();

        res = (((socE*100)/socT)*2350)/100.0;
        return res;
    }

    //Voluntarietat, Utilitació d'instalacions municipals i organització d'events en festes locals i de formació.
    public double calculEvents(int i) {
        double res = 0;
        if (subs.get(i).getFestes() == true) {
            res += calculFestes();
        }
        if (subs.get(i).getFormacio()== true) {
            res += calculFormacio();
        }
        if (subs.get(i).getInstalacions()== true) {
            res += calculInstalacions();
        }
        if (subs.get(i).getVoluntari() == true) {
            res += calculVoluntari();
        }
        return res;
    }

    public double calculFestes() {
        return festesTotals()/940.0;
    }

    public double calculFormacio() {
        return formacioTotals()/940.0;
    }

    public double calculVoluntari() {
        return voluntariTotals()/470.0;
    }

    public double calculInstalacions() {
        return instalacionsTotals()/2350.0;
    }

    //Mètodes per al calcul de la cuantitat total de elements que hi ha a la llista de subvencions
    public int equipsTotals(){
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
           res += subs.get(i).getEquips();
        }
        return res;

    }
    public int despesesTotals(){
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
           res += subs.get(i).getDespeses();
        }
        return res;  
    }
    public int esportistesTotals(){
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
           res += subs.get(i).getEsportistes();
        }
        return res;

    }
    public int puntuacioTotals(){
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
           res += subs.get(i).getPuntuacio();
        }
        return res;

    }
    public int socisTotals(){
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
           res += subs.get(i).getSocis();
        }
        return res;

    }
    public int festesTotals() {
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
            if (subs.get(i).getFestes() == true) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public int formacioTotals() {
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
            if (subs.get(i).getFormacio()== true) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public int voluntariTotals() {
         int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
            if (subs.get(i).getVoluntari()== true) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public int instalacionsTotals() {
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < subs.size(); i++){
            if (subs.get(i).getInstalacions() == true) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    //metode per a editar una subvenció.
    @FXML
    private void editar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/model/Afegir.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        AfegirController controlador = loader.getController();
        if(tabla.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
            DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
            dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
            dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error al editar un element.");
            alert.setContentText("Deus seleccionar un element per porder utilitzar aquesta opció.");
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        }
        else{
            controlador.inicializaSubvencio(tabla.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage ventana2= new Stage();
            ventana2.setTitle("Editar");
            ventana2.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            ventana2.setScene(scene);
            ventana2.showAndWait();
            tabla.setItems(subs);
        }


    }
}



package controlador;

import dades.Subvencio;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Regidors
 */
public class AfegirController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField esport;
    @FXML
    private TextField equips;
    @FXML
    private TextField despeses;
    @FXML
    private TextField esportistes;
    @FXML
    private TextField puntuacio;
    @FXML
    private TextField socis;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox festes;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox disiplina;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox voluntari;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox instalacions;
    @FXML
    private Button bafegir;
    @FXML
    private Button bcancelar;
    Subvencio sub = new Subvencio();

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
    //Metode per a afegir una subvencio a la llista de elements.
    @FXML
    private void afegir(ActionEvent event) {
        //Comprobem si tots els textfielsd estan omplits, sino es així, mostrem un error.
         if ((!equips.getText().isEmpty())
            && (equips.getText().trim().length()!=0)
            && (!despeses.getText().isEmpty())
            && (despeses.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!esportistes.getText().isEmpty())
            && (esportistes.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!puntuacio.getText().isEmpty())
            && (puntuacio.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!socis.getText().isEmpty())
            && (socis.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!esport.getText().isEmpty())
            && (esport.getText().trim().length()!=0))
         { 
             //Passem els valors de el textfield als seus corresponents formats.
            int aux1 = Integer.parseInt(equips.getText());
            double aux2 = Double.parseDouble(despeses.getText());
            int aux3 = Integer.parseInt(esportistes.getText());
            int aux4 = Integer.parseInt(puntuacio.getText());
            int aux5 = Integer.parseInt(socis.getText());
            boolean aux6 = festes.isPressed();
            boolean aux7 = disiplina.isPressed();
            boolean aux8 = voluntari.isPressed();
            boolean aux9 = instalacions.isPressed();
            String aux10 = esport.getText();
           //Carregem un controllardor per poder crear subvencions i la creeem. en cabar aques proces la finestra es tanca.
           GeneralController aux = new GeneralController();
           sub.setEsport(aux10);
           sub.setEquips(aux1);
           sub.setEsportistes(aux3);
           sub.setFestes(aux6);
           sub.setFormacio(aux7);
           sub.setInstalacions(aux9);
           sub.setPuntuacio(aux4);
           sub.setSocis(aux5);
           sub.setVoluntari(aux8);
           sub.setdespeses(aux2);
           aux.subs.add(sub);
           Node minodo = (Node) event.getSource(); 
           minodo.getScene().getWindow().hide();
         }
         else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
            DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
            dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
            dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error al afegir una subvenció.");
            alert.setContentText("Deus emplenar tots els cuadres de text per poder afegir una subvenció.");
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

         }
    }
    //Mètode per cancelar la creació d'una subvenció.
    @FXML
    private void cancelar(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
        DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
        dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
        dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
        alert.setTitle("Confirmació");
        alert.setHeaderText("No has guardat la subvenció");
        alert.setContentText("¿Segur que vols tancar la finestra i descartar la subvencó?");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            System.out.println("Acceptar");
            Node minodo = (Node) event.getSource(); 
            minodo.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cancel·lar");
        }
    }
    public void inicializaSubvencio (Subvencio aux){
        sub = aux;
        String aux1 = String.valueOf(aux.getEsport());
        String aux2 = String.valueOf(aux.getEquips());
        String aux3 = String.valueOf(aux.getDespeses());
        String aux4 = String.valueOf(aux.getEsportistes());
        String aux5 = String.valueOf(aux.getEsportistes());
        String aux6 = String.valueOf(aux.getPuntuacio());
        String aux7 = String.valueOf(aux.getSocis());
        esport.setText(aux1);
        equips.setText(aux2);
        despeses.setText(aux3);
        esportistes.setText(aux5);
        puntuacio.setText(aux6);
        socis.setText(aux7);
        festes.setSelected(aux.getFestes());
        disiplina.setSelected(aux.getFormacio());
        voluntari.setSelected(aux.getVoluntari());
        instalacions.setSelected(aux.getInstalacions());
    }

}
```

Espero que podais ayudarme con mi duda.
Muchas gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Según veo, estás inicializando `subs` desde una lista vacía. ¿Por qué entonces esperas que tenga resultados para mostrar en tu tabla?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He editado el post con mas datos. La idea del codigo es pasar mediante Afegir los datos recogidos en los textfield y mostrar solo 2 de ellos en la tabla. He intentado ponerlo como variable global pero tampoco ha resultado.